# Render issue- my partly transparent mesh won't render

Tags: rendering

So I am trying to go this animation (using a pre existing rig and all)
and for some reason my bg and the partly transparent mesh won't render in teh final immage

[image]

I am not certain how to fix this any help is welcome nya

[image]

Comment: Try selecting the objects that are not rendered, and check in the outline that the camera icon is enabled next to the name.

Comment: there are too many possibilities to create the behavior you see. please provide the .blend file at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com for others to test. remember to pack the textures if possible

Comment: I know the Item should be rendered in the final as teh camera option is corectly ticked.